# Date Difference Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sos

My database has a table in which it has two date columns (`Start Date` and `End Date`)

How can I list all the dates where the difference of `Start Date` and `End Date` is no more than 15 days?

This is what i tried so far:

```
SELECT homeworkID, subject, startdate, dateadd(day,15,startdate) as enddate
FROM homework;
```

Comment: In your example Start Date and End Date always have difference 15 days.

Comment: why isn't it just where end_dt - start_dt <= 15 ?

Comment: Your predicate should handle it simply, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the filter predicate as per your rule/logic :

```
Select start_date, 
       end_date, 
       other_columns
  From table
 Where end_date - start_date <= 15
```

Comment: I agree, a simple expression like this is the correct approach.

Comment: @LalitKumarB thanks a lot that helped me out, i would love to do it without asking but sometimes so much coding is hectic but appreciate your helps